# Datagrip table prefixs when expanding column lists

Tags: datagrip

Is there a way to make datagrip define the columns table names every time when I use the lightbulb to expand the column list from `SELECT *`. Right now, it will only explicitly define the table if there are 2 fields that are in common among the tables. I wish for it to do it for all the columns.

```
--example of what it does now
SELECT 
       a.id
     , number
     , name
     , b.id
 FROM       a
 INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id


--Desired result with all columns prefixed
    SELECT 
       a.id
     , a.number
     , a.name
     , b.id
 FROM       a
 INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

1. Go to *Settings | Editor | General | Smart keys*
2. Go to *SQL section*
3. Put **Always** into *Table* and *Alias*

[image]

PS: you can also select all needed columns -> *Alt+Enter* -> *Qualify*.

Comment: Awesome,  I went ahead and tested it and it worked thank you.